# Can't insert into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do an INSERT on a MySQL table, but I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Key, CallID, Number, Region, TaskType, TaskCategory, AssignmentStart, Assignment' at line 1

The Insert query is the following:

```
INSERT INTO tableauperformance.clickperformance (Key, CallID, Number, Region, TaskType, TaskCategory, AssignmentStart, AssignmentFinish, OnSiteDate, TravelDate, Street, Priority, District, TCCanal3, TCCanal50, TCCanal70, TCCanal110, TCCanal116, TCComments, TCComentarioOrden, TCAcciones, TCAfectacion, TCTipoCierre, TCCodigoCierre, TCRazonesDeSuspencion, TCRazonesDeIncomplete, Status, AssignedEngineer) VALUES(1215963143, "190820PD0109", 1, "Ore Provincia", "PD  Edificio Sin señal", "Problema Domiciliario", "2019-09-16 10:43:00", "2019-09-16 15:01:00", null, null, "TERRERO 1328", 50, "RedSur Red", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "Cliente: 3985232Orden: 13369560TERRERO 1362 / BURZACOObservaciones: Directa bajaTAP: 17x8TAP ubicado en: 1339Medicion TAP: Directa -1.1Mer 36.0Ber ok Retorno 40.150 8.1  70 7.5116 8.4136 9.4Abonados Afectados: 1347, Se llega a sitio se toman mediciones en tap 17x8 ubicado en la calle Torrero 1339 niveles Ch03 15.0 ch70 9.3 ch115 2.8  ch116 7.4  ch 4.9 Docsis Mer Ber  ok 40.3 se chequea amplificador HGD ubicado en la calle sempere 1356 Niveles de entrada Ch03 22.6 ch70 24.2 ch115 19.3  ch116 23.9 ch136 23.6  Niveles de salida antes del ajuste ch03 29.5 ch70 47.6 ch115 48.7ch116 50. 1  ch136 53.6 Niveles después del ajuste ch03 42.1 ch70 50.5 ch115 48.0 ch116 53.2  ch136 54.5  Docsis 33.5 Materiales se gasto  pad de 0 . 1 . 8 Inv 4.5 Se recuperó pad de 2.25  . 0 . 12 EQ 13.5Se suspende ticket por tareas conmayor prioridad caída de nodo AD27BSe midió tap 17*8 ubicado en terrero 1339Ch3:14.570:16.1116:17.3136:19.4Docsis:39.6Mer:38.7Ber:ok.Confirma cierre técnico personal de base.", "Correctiva", "SI", "Finalizada","Ecualización", "Caída de Nodo o Tkt de Mayor Prioridad" , null, "Completed", "Hoyos Jonathan Emanuel");
```

The table structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableauperformance`.`clickperformance` (
  `Key` INT NOT NULL,
  `CallID` VARCHAR(12) NULL,
  `Number` INT NULL,
  `Region` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `TaskType` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `TaskCategory` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `AssignmentStart` DATE NULL,
  `AssignmentFinish` DATE NULL,
  `OnSiteDate` DATE NULL,
  `TravelDate` DATE NULL,
  `Street` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `Priority` INT NULL,
  `Duration` FLOAT NULL,
  `District` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `TCCanal3` FLOAT NULL,
  `TCCanal50` FLOAT NULL,
  `TCCanal70` FLOAT NULL,
  `TCCanal110` FLOAT NULL,
  `TCCanal116` FLOAT NULL,
  `TCComments` TEXT NULL,
  `TCComentarioOrden` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
  `TCAcciones` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TCAfectacion` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `TCTipoCierre` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `TCCodigoCierre` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `TCRazonesDeSuspencion` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `TCRazonesDeIncomplete` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `Status` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `AssignedEngineer` TINYTEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Key`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
```

Are you being able to see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: is `Key` not a reserved word in MySQL? You might want to call the `Key` column something else. Otherwise wrap your column names with ` in your insert statement.

Comment: Did you try encapsulating your schema name and table name using the ` characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you are using one of SQL keywords as a column name.

You have column name key which is also a keyword. Try below,

```
INSERT INTO tableauperformance.clickperformance (`Key`, CallID, Number, Region, TaskType, TaskCategory, AssignmentStart, AssignmentFinish, OnSiteDate, TravelDate, Street, Priority, District, TCCanal3, TCCanal50, TCCanal70, TCCanal110, TCCanal116, TCComments, TCComentarioOrden, TCAcciones, TCAfectacion, TCTipoCierre, TCCodigoCierre, TCRazonesDeSuspencion, TCRazonesDeIncomplete, Status, AssignedEngineer) VALUES(1215963143, "190820PD0109", 1, "Ore Provincia", "PD  Edificio Sin señal", "Problema Domiciliario", "2019-09-16 10:43:00", "2019-09-16 15:01:00", null, null, "TERRERO 1328", 50, "RedSur Red", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "Cliente: 3985232Orden: 13369560TERRERO 1362 / BURZACOObservaciones: Directa bajaTAP: 17x8TAP ubicado en: 1339Medicion TAP: Directa -1.1Mer 36.0Ber ok Retorno 40.150 8.1  70 7.5116 8.4136 9.4Abonados Afectados: 1347, Se llega a sitio se toman mediciones en tap 17x8 ubicado en la calle Torrero 1339 niveles Ch03 15.0 ch70 9.3 ch115 2.8  ch116 7.4  ch 4.9 Docsis Mer Ber  ok 40.3 se chequea amplificador HGD ubicado en la calle sempere 1356 Niveles de entrada Ch03 22.6 ch70 24.2 ch115 19.3  ch116 23.9 ch136 23.6  Niveles de salida antes del ajuste ch03 29.5 ch70 47.6 ch115 48.7ch116 50. 1  ch136 53.6 Niveles después del ajuste ch03 42.1 ch70 50.5 ch115 48.0 ch116 53.2  ch136 54.5  Docsis 33.5 Materiales se gasto  pad de 0 . 1 . 8 Inv 4.5 Se recuperó pad de 2.25  . 0 . 12 EQ 13.5Se suspende ticket por tareas conmayor prioridad caída de nodo AD27BSe midió tap 17*8 ubicado en terrero 1339Ch3:14.570:16.1116:17.3136:19.4Docsis:39.6Mer:38.7Ber:ok.Confirma cierre técnico personal de base.", "Correctiva", "SI", "Finalizada","Ecualización", "Caída de Nodo o Tkt de Mayor Prioridad" , null, "Completed", "Hoyos Jonathan Emanuel");
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that worked